# How to save using the Mercury editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, mercury-editor

I want to get the save function in the Mercury editor working but to no avail.

I have a model to save the page, title and content.

mercury.js:

```
$(window).bind('mercury:ready', function() {
 var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
 Mercury.saveURL = link.data('save-url');
 link.hide();
});

$(window).bind('mercury:saved', function() {
 window.location = window.location.href.replace(/\/editor\//i, '/');
});
```

static_pages_controller.rb:

```
def update
  @static_page = StaticPage.find(params[:id])
  @static_page.page = params[:page]
  @static_page.title = params[:content][:aboutContainer][:value][:about_title][:value]
  @static_page.content = params[:content][:aboutContainer][:value][:about_content][:value]

@static_page.save!
render plain: ''
end
```

about.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'About') %>
  <div class="container" id="aboutContainer" data-mercury="full">
    <h1 id="about_title"><%= raw @static_page.title %></h1>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p id="description about_content"><%= raw @static_page.content %></p>
    </div>
    <p><%= link_to "Edit Page", "/editor" + request.path, id: "edit_link", 
        data: {save_url: static_page_update_path(@static_page)} %></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is there any error output? can you check that `@static_page.save!` is working?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass) - that's the error I get.

Comment: Well then, `StaticPage.find_by(page: request.path)` doesn't find your page. Does it exist in the db?

Comment: yep, it exists as: => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<StaticPage id: 1, title: "About", content: "content", created_at: "2017-04-28 09:45:00", updated_at: "2017-04-28 09:45:00", page: "about">]>

Comment: Note I don't think it gets up to mercury_update method in the controller because binding.pry doesn't get hit.

Comment: `page: "about"`, right, and what is the value of `request.path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i basically realised that I needed a show action so I can grab records from the model and save to the @static_page object

I was following this guide: http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor?autoplay=true

Please note I had to change my routes to using those in the link (or similar routes to them) and had to place them before the default mercury routes and had to change:

```
@static_page.title = params[:content][:aboutContainer][:value][:about_title][:value]
@static_page.content = params[:content][:aboutContainer][:value][:about_content][:value]
```

to:

```
@static_page.title = params[:content][:about_title][:value]
@static_page.content = params[:content][:about_content][:value]
```

I then removed the class 'container' div in about.html.erb and moved all the code to show.html.erb not needing about.html.erb.